# Determine the differentiability of two functions at point x0

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to determine if the following functions: $$f(x)=|x-1|^3 \\ g(x)=\sqrt{|x-1|+1}$$ are differentialble at the point $x_0=1$.
My approach:

$$If\quad x-1\geq 0 :f(x)=(x-1)^3$$
$$ \lim\limits_{x \to x_0}{\frac{(x-1)^3-(x_0-1)^3}{x-x_0}}=\lim\limits_{x \to 1}{\frac{(x-1)^3-(1-1)^3}{x-1}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}{\frac{(x-1)^3}{x-1}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}{(x-1)^2}=0$$
$$If\quad x-1<0:f(x)=-(x-1)^3$$
$$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}{\frac{-(x-1)^3+(x_0-1)^3}{x-x_0}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}{\frac{-(x-1)^3}{x-1}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}-(x-1)^2=0$$
This function is differentiable at the point $x_0$, because the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}$ exists.

$$If\quad x-1\geq 0 : g(x)=\sqrt{(x-1)+1}=\sqrt{x}$$
$$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}{\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}}{x-x_0}}=\lim\limits_{x \to 1}{\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{x-1}}*\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}+1}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}{\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$If x-1<0: g(x)=\sqrt{-(x-1)+1}=\sqrt{-x+2}$$
$$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}{\frac{\sqrt{-x+2}-\sqrt{-x_0+2}}{x-x_0}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}{\frac{\sqrt{-x+2}-1}{x-1}}*\frac{\sqrt{-x+2}+1}{\sqrt{-x+2}+1}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}{\frac{-x+1}{(x-1)(\sqrt{-x+2}+1)}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{-x+2}+1}}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
The function g(x) is also differentiable, because the limits exist.

Is my approach correct? Or have I done everything flawless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good idea to plot the function first. This doesn't really help
with the first, but indicates an issue with the second.

For the first, note that
${f(h+1)-f(1) \over h} = h^2$, hence $\lim_{h \to 0} {f(h+1)-f(1) \over h} = 0$.

For the second, note that
$\lim_{h \uparrow 0} {g(h+1)-g(1) \over h} = \lim_{h \uparrow 0} {\sqrt{1-h}-1 \over h} = -{ 1\over 2}$ and
$\lim_{h \downarrow 0} {g(h+1)-g(1) \over h} = \lim_{h \uparrow 0} {\sqrt{1+h}-1 \over h} = { 1\over 2}$. Hence $g$ is **not** differentiable
at $x=1$ (if a function is differentiable, then the limits must agree).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although there is a typo at lines $5$ and $7$; it should be
$$
If\quad x-1\geq 0 :f(x)=(x-1)^3
$$
$$
If\quad x-1\leq 0 :f(x)=-(x-1)^3
$$
Respectively. Otherwise, that statement makes no sense to the actual absolute value. Same goes for lines $10$ and $12$.